# Matching chars in a string type

Tags: typescript, types, type-inference

Hope you are well. I have a question. I'm looking to make a type that loops through a string one char at a time and if all of the chars match the lookup chars then it should return the string and if not it should return never or a empty string. Been having some trouble with this because what i have basically behaves like `Trim` and that is not really what i am looking for. As i am looking for more of a pattern matching type. Hoping you can provide some help with this and thanks in advance!

```
type Char =
  | "0" | "1" | "2" | "3" | "4" | "5" | "6" | "7"
  | "8" | "9" | "a" | "A" | "b" | "B" | "c" | "C"
  | "d" | "D" | "e" | "E" | "f" | "F";

type Word<S extends string> = S extends `${Char}${infer Rest}` ? Word<Rest> : never;
```

Code: [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKgBA+l09YJoHsCuAnMBhRATApmACV1X1jKjBGAChqAXATwAd8MALAQ3QF5qx+wAHzAAiAAwi+A4SICMkgUNEAmBdNEBmNfxkAWbUpEBWAzIBsp0QHZLIgBy2AnLY62AgrYBGtgEK2AxrYYtti2ACK2uLYAorYAZrYAYiIA3LSMLGAA6oio2AA8AMpguAAedLgAdtgAzmA1dKgAlpUA5gB8YNxgxWUV1XUABgAkAN7sXAC+Yy1xxGAASrgNk4NSAPzZuQVLDZ0AXGCVuABuxGnUoJDksGAAKst0mBw1y9c3cFTUTQC2TLlPDL4UZgaIAR2QHAANgAaUGlFj+J6TMBxVCIH5gADkAAEgQBafycKFQqqtZbAZB0JpQmpY9LMfD+F5vboAbSk0QRuCR+XBkKh+RyeXy4lkyg0uiMZisdmc7ThYolUplcpE7QVnO5vP50KF21FHE8YVwug0yl0UqMujCcSN-n8GFCCtERpNZotVptds8Dqd6s1-C5iLofIheuFBTFAHE7TVsHEAO64JMp9Vw45nVAamHUAC6tGAwDAeJq+LKIfLqHRqHojJK1dyXS2IvFkulsscYnatEL4A+MDAiTQdDY80KFSYdQHnxooCknUKnBIYAYKHQNUQUKpTUQlRqhzYdDoU-2RboNSJADoAFY1K+5VrAWQaYAcffJ2v8ToANSauETeotx3PcDzAI8TwPc9LzYW970fZ9X03bdqVAhcwAAWVyVhiVJNplkPY9T2g687wfVBWmoL5qCAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the original string and return it if the string is empty:

```
type Word<S extends string, Original = S> = S extends `${infer _ extends Char}${infer Rest}`
  ? Word<Rest, Original> : S extends "" ? Original : never;
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/w1A4lw)